# Which tinkerpop graph databases do not support specifying an id?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

The [gremlin documentation](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_the_graph_structure) says:

> Many graph vendors do not allow the user to specify an element ID and
>   in such cases, an exception is thrown.

I assume this refers to only specifying an ID when creating a new vertex or edge, not to the overall use of IDs in queries. So which gremlin implementations do, and which do not allow specifying and ID along with vertex or edge creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to specify the graph databases that do allow id assignment rather than those that don't as most graph databases do not allow you to specify the id when you create a vertex/edge.

I'm only aware of two that allow you to specify the id: TinkerGraph and [elastic-gremlin](https://github.com/rmagen/elastic-gremlin).  The rest do not support that.

You can always check what a graph supports by calling the `features()` method on the `Graph` instance:

http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#_features

Comment: Excellent. This helps deciding about specifying the ID in an application that wishes to be database neutral!

Comment: The features command also very helpful in this exact context! hopefully tinkerpop 3 will make it to any graph database soon, haven't seen any support so far other than a dubious statement on IBM Bluemix.

Comment: The list of databases that support TP3 are on the apache TinkerPop home page - see the "Implementations" section - http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/ - we expect to see more.  BlazeGraph announced they will support TP3 in their next release 1.6 and OrientDB will look to support it in 3.0 toward the end of the year as of their last statement.  That would give general coverage of most of the graphs out there.  was there one in particular that you were looking for?

Comment: Titan has had several milestone releases that supported TP3 prior to the recently released 1.0.  Perhaps BlueMix was built on one of those early milestones.

Comment: Stardog 4.0 will have TinkerPop3 support. http://blog.stardog.com/a-preview-of-stardog-4/ A release candidate is expected Sep 30, 2015. https://twitter.com/stardog_db/status/646752972840521728

Comment: Gee, Stardog, I guess the industry's running out of names :)